# "No space left on device: AH00023: Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex" when restarting httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache2, httpd, cpanel

My server sometimes gets filled up with connections in apache stuck in a "Sending Reply" state, requiring me to restart apache. Most of the time this works, but sometimes I will get this error when trying to restart apache instead:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with
error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe"
for details.
```

Running `systemctl status httpd.service` or `journalctl -xe` as suggested then brings back the following relevant information:

```
Nov 15 06:24:06 hostname.biologyreporter.com systemd-logind[874]:
 Failed to remove runtime directory /run/user/1067: Device or resource busy

Nov 15 06:24:27 hostname.biologyreporter.com restartsrv_httpd[29484]:
 [Fri Nov 15 06:24:27.255594 2019] [core:emerg] [pid 29509:tid 47498001208384]
 (28) No space left on device: AH00023: Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex  
 
Nov 15 06:24:27 hostname.biologyreporter.com restartsrv_httpd[29484]:
 (28) No space left on device: could not create accept mutex  
 
Nov 15 06:24:27 hostname.biologyreporter.com restartsrv_httpd[29484]:
 AH00015: Unable to open logs

Nov 15 06:24:27 hostname.biologyreporter.com systemd[1]:
 httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1  
 
Nov 15 06:24:27 hostname.biologyreporter.com systemd[1]:
 Failed to start Apache web server managed by cPanel EasyApache.
 -- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
```

It may then take ~10 minutes or so for apache to actually restart and the website to be functional again. I don't know why it is saying "No space left on device" as running `df`, for example, returns the following (nowhere is 100% of space taken):

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         3973024         0   3973024   0% /dev
tmpfs            3983400         0   3983400   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            3983400    255296   3728104   7% /run
tmpfs            3983400         0   3983400   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2      952008348 137586024 766039760  16% /
/dev/sda1         999320    134892    795616  15% /boot
/dev/loop0       3997376      8856   3778808   1% /tmp
tmpfs             796684         0    796684   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs             796684         0    796684   0% /run/user/1022
```

I've been unable to find any reliable information on the cause and solution of the specific error(s) as listed above

- `No space left on device: AH00023: Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex` and
- `Failed to remove runtime directory /run/user/1067: Device or resource busy`

What should I do to solve this so that these errors don't show up and apache always restarts without issues?

Comment: what if you do "df -i" instead?

Comment: Loads of free space for everything

Answer (score 18):

This is most likely caused by the semaphore limit of the OS, and Apache not properly cleaning up after itself.

See more details about semaphore limits https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/tuning_and_optimizing_red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_oracle_9i_and_10g_databases/sect-oracle_9i_and_10g_tuning_guide-setting_semaphores-setting_semaphore_parameters

Those errors mean that there is a lack of inner-process communication resources in the system, such as semaphores or shared memory segments.
Try running next to see if the semaphore limit is reached and see results:

```
ipcs -s | wc -l

cat /proc/sys/kernel/msgmni

cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem
```

Execute the following command via SSH or console and see if it helps :

```
ipcs -s | awk -v user=apache '$3==user {system("ipcrm -s "$2)}'
```

`ipcs -s` lists currently used semaphores.

`awk -v user=apache` filters out the ones, owned by apache user and next part executes `icprm -s "id"` for each of it which removes that semaphore.

I.e., whole command removes all semaphores owned by apache user.

Comment: what does the command `ipcs -s | awk -v user=apache '$3==user {system("ipcrm -s "$2)}'` do?

Comment: @user548654, `ipcs -s` lists currently used semaphores. `awk -v user=apache` filters out the ones, owned by apache user and next part executes `icprm -s "id"` for each of it which removes that semaphore. I.e. whole command removes all semaphores owned by apache user.

Comment: @NStorm thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! `ipcs -s | awk -v user=apache '$3==user {system("ipcrm -s "$2)}'` command fixed it for me!!!

Comment: Beautiful answer, helped me out thanks

Comment: is there a fix for apache not cleaning up after itself?

Answer (score 6):

While the answer by @dzup4uk seems to be able to point out what the issue is, in order to actually solve the issue you have to ensure that the semaphores get cleaned up.
`ipcs` command will show what the issue is but in order to actually solve the issue you have to do some cleaning which can be done with

```
ipcrm -a
```

Comment: Good tip here @Barnabas Busa. One small observation. On my system, I found semaphores being used by root associated with critical system processes. Perhaps it would be best to instead use `ipcrm -s <semid>` so that a semaphore associated with a critical system process is not removed?

Comment: Please, do not execute this command on production, as i just figured it out the command above stops apache - So obviously it will affect your clients, do at a time where no one is using it.

Comment: @Barnabas Busa answer helped ...
ipcrm -a
...

Answer (score 0):

If your Apache is running under the nobody user then you need to run it with nobody like so:

```
ipcs -s | awk -v user=nobody '$3==user {system("ipcrm -s "$2)}'
```